# Merge multiple dictionaries and aggregate values where required

Tags: c#, linq

I have three Dictionaries created by calling ToDictionary on a GroupBy projection in LINQ.

```
var dictionaryOne = _repositoryOne.GetData()
.GroupBy(d => new { d.Property1, d.Property2, d.LocalCcyId})
.ToDictionary(d =>
    new
    {
        d.Key.Property1,
        d.Key.Property2,
        d.Key.LocalCcyId
    },
    v => v.Sum(l => ConvertToUsd(effectiveDate, l.LocalCcyId, l.Amount))); 

var dictionaryTwo = _repositoryTwo.GetData()
.GroupBy(d => new { d.Property1, d.Property2, d.LocalCcyId})
.ToDictionary(d =>
    new
    {
        d.Key.Property1,
        d.Key.Property2,
        d.Key.LocalCcyId
    },
    v => v.Sum(l => ConvertToUsd(effectiveDate, l.LocalCcyId, l.Balance))); 

var dictionaryThree = _repositoryThree.GetData()
.GroupBy(d => new { d.Property1, d.Property2, d.LocalCcyId})
.ToDictionary(d =>
    new
    {
        d.Key.Property1,
        d.Key.Property2,
        d.Key.LocalCcyId
    },
    v => v.Sum(l => ConvertToUsd(effectiveDate, l.LocalCcyId, l.Total)));
```

I want to merge these into a dictionary and 
i) Sum up the values which are in USD &
ii) Drop the grouping by LocalCcyId column from the Key

The will be instances to the same key occurring in each of the three dictionaries and I need to aggregate the Sums for all such cases. How do I achieve this in LINQ?

Comment: Why don't you just `Concat` your data sources before you do the `ToDictionary` call?

Comment: I can try that. The data structure of each of the sources is very different and I'll have to do an extra Select on each of them to make them work with Concat.

Comment: @nvoigt - I tried but couldn't get it to work. If I do a Select after GroupBy then I can't call ToDictionary on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that this is all you need:

```
var finalDictionary =
    dictionaryOne
        .Concat(dictionaryTwo)
        .Concat(dictionaryThree)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.Property1, x.Key.Property2 }, x => x.Value)
        .ToDictionary(x => new { x.Key.Property1, x.Key.Property2 }, x => x.Sum());
```

Or, using LINQ syntax (as much as possible) this:

```
var finalDictionary =
(
    from x in dictionaryOne.Concat(dictionaryTwo).Concat(dictionaryThree)
    group x.Value by new { x.Key.Property1, x.Key.Property2 }
)
    .ToDictionary(x => new { x.Key.Property1, x.Key.Property2 }, x => x.Sum());
```

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is there are "duplicate" keys in each of the dictionaries. For these cases I need to aggregate the values for the key (Sum).

Comment: @RahulMisra - No, that shouldn't be a problem. The group by gets rid of duplicates.

Comment: It does indeed. Just to be sure, I looked at the Concat implementation which just returns all the elements from each of the collections given to it and GroupBy then does the job of aggregating it up. I compared the results with another block of three foreach loops iterating over each dictionary and aggregating the values when a key seen before is encountered. The numbers in both cases match exactly. I understand this  better now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are querying a remote datasource, running queries twice over the data or convering to USD twice doesn't seem more efficient then taking the dictionaries and combining them, so that's what I did.

First you need to convert each `Dictionary` to a new anonymous object having the data you need, then group by the properties summing the values:

```
var allDictionary = dictionaryOne.Select(kv => new { kv.Key.Property1, kv.Key.Property2, kv.Value })
                                 .Concat(dictionaryTwo.Select(kv => new { kv.Key.Property1, kv.Key.Property2, kv.Value }))
                                 .Concat(dictionaryThree.Select(kv => new { kv.Key.Property1, kv.Key.Property2, kv.Value }))
                                 .GroupBy(k2v => new { k2v.Property1, k2v.Property2 })
                                 .ToDictionary(k2vg => new { k2vg.Key.Property1, k2vg.Key.Property2 }, k2vg => k2vg.Sum(k2v => k2v.Value));
```